# CSS bootstrap having a weird issue with a navbars margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, navbar

So I'm building a website, and I have a weird problem with my navbar. Note I am using bootstrap, but this navbar is not a bootstrap navbar.

First of all I'm gonna paste in my code.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="toppic">
<!-- Logo -->
<img src="logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="log">
</div>
<div class="line">
</div>
<div class="navy">
    <ul class="navul">


        <li class="navli"> <a href="index.php">  </a> <div class="testbox active home"> Home </div>    </li>
        <li class="navli"> <a href="about.php">  </a> <div class="testbox"> About </div> </li>
        <li class="navli"> <a href="goals.php">  </a> <div class="testbox  "> Goals </div> </li>
        <li class="navli"> <a href="partners.php">  </a> <div class="testbox"> Partners </div> </li>
        <li class="navli"> <a href="contact.php">  </a> <div class="testbox"> Contact </div> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#nav
{
position: relative;
left: 3%;

width: 97% !important;
margin: 0px !important;

}
.line
{
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
height: 1px;
width: 70%;
position:absolute;
top: 36%;
left:23%;
}
.navy
{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 55%;
width: 35%;
}
 .toppic
{
width: 94% !important;
margin: 0px !important;
}
#log
{
 margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;

}
```

Now the problem is that the navbar has an unwanted margin on the right side, even after applying margin: 0px !important to the entire navbar.
It is only visible when you are not viewing the website in full-screen (at least on my monitor). The problem with this margin is that it adds a horizontal scrollbar to the website, and when you scroll to the right there is a blank area without any elements, caused by this margin.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

**Note** I did not include the other classes because on inspecting the navbar in chrome I can see that they do not have the weird margin, only 
     `<div id="nav">`
has it. Not it's sub-elements
     .
On request I will add the other classes too.

**EDIT** Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9s7st15/
 (note that this has some unused css classes, but at least the problem shows up). The Jsfiddle has some other bugs caused by the fact that I didn't include a lot of my CSS but like I said, the problem I wanted to solve is present too.

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link

Comment: Why don't you just use `float`?

Comment: Do you mean to ensure the elements are next to each other instead of stacked? I did. the navli class has a `float:left`

Comment: I mean instead of all those `position`'s and `margin`'s

Comment: Because I am a newbie and this is my first site, I did not think about using float at all. After some googling it appears to be quite handy.I will do this if I ever build a site again, and may edit this site to use it later. But for now I want this problem fixed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have adjusted your css:

```
.navy {
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: 55%; Remove left margin */
    width: 35%;
    right: 0;
}
```

And for #nav I have changed left: 0;

Comment: This did not work for me. There is still a scrollbar which on scrolling right reveals a white area, although the margin thing is indeed fixed. What else could be causing this white area?

Comment: Nevermind. I am an idiot. There was another image further down the page which did not have a right: 0; property. It stuck out a bit, widening the page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused by a margin on the body, if you add a `margin:0` it will get rid of it.

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d5qt5x4x/

Answer (score -1):

remove this line margin-left: 55%;

Comment: Please format code as code. And please, explain your solution a little bit more.

Comment: .navy
{
position: absolute;
width: 35%;
}

Comment: Please read through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please edit your answer to include further details. By the way, just posting more code is not an explanation.